# How to skip unless cell contains value?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to skip or exit an if routine and go on to the next one if the first line doesn't meet the criteria.
READ: ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = "F".

This sub is placed in the Change event.

I tried `If Not ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = "F" Then Exit Sub`.
Which in this case just killed the whole routine.

I tried to split it into five different subs and tried to call them from the change event sub. I get errors.

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Target.Offset(0, -1) = Now
    
    'Written by Bjoern Monroe (04.27.2019) - [Rev 1]
    
    'If the above cell is = L then the selected cell can't contain "VS" or "VN"
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = "L" Then
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Text = "VS" Or ActiveCell.Text = "VN" Then
        MsgBox ("Trigger Warning")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Wont Trigger Warning")
    End If
    
    'If the above cell is = F then the selected cell can't contain "VS" or "VN"
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = "F" Then
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Text = "VS" Or ActiveCell.Text = "VN" Then
        MsgBox ("Trigger Warning")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Wont Trigger Warning")
    End If
    
    'If the above cell is = S then the selected cell can't contain "L", "VS", "F", or "S"
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = "S" Then
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Text = "L" Or ActiveCell.Text = "VS" Or ActiveCell.Text = "F" Or ActiveCell.Text = "S" Then
        MsgBox ("Trigger Warning")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Wont Trigger Warning")
    End If
    
    'If the above cell is = VN then the selected cell can't contain "L", "VN", "F", or "S"
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = "VN" Then
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Text = "L" Or ActiveCell.Text = "VN" Or ActiveCell.Text = "F" Or ActiveCell.Text = "S" Then
        MsgBox ("Trigger Warning")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Wont Trigger Warning")
    End If
    
    'If the above cell is = VS then the selected cell can't contain "VS", "L", Or "S"
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = "VS" Then
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Text = "VS" Or ActiveCell.Text = "L" Or ActiveCell.Text = "S" Then
        MsgBox ("Trigger Warning")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Wont Trigger Warning")
    End If
    
End Sub
```

I have a column which always gets populated by a user with F, L, S, VN and VS.
But the sequence of value which are populated is almost always the same.
If the column cell above is F, the activecell can only be F, L, or S. Never VN or VS for instance. I want the user to get a popup message that tells them they are about to write the wrong sequence.

I get five popup boxes, instead of one. Which makes sense because the sub thinks I want to check for all five if it meets the criteria or not.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think you should delete de `ElseIf` inside `If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = "VS" Then` and change it to a second `If`. Right now, your code just check `If the above cell is = VS` and, **if not** then it checks if selected cell contain "VS", "L", Or "S". It is not behaving as you wish.

Comment: Why do you have `ElseIf`s indented?  Should those be `If`s instead?  Then you can chain together your `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)` checks with `ElseIf`s properly

Comment: Thanks alot so far for the attention and pointers. Ive been reading them all and are testing them out right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first step would be to fix the `If` **syntax**, as the `ElseIf` should not be indented and you're executing nothing if your condition is met. 
 
I also added a check for the `ActiveCell.Column`, because if you select any row on the first column, your code will throw an Error:

```
    'If the above cell is = L then the selected cell can't contain "VS" or "VN"
    If ActiveCell.Column > 1 Then
        If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = "L" Then
            'Nothing to execute?
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Text = "VS" Or ActiveCell.Text = "VN" Then
            MsgBox ("Trigger Warning")
        Else
            MsgBox ("Wont Trigger Warning")
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: +1 for spotting the ElseIf syntax error. @bmonroe, note that and `ElseIf` statement is equal to saying "If the previous If (or ElseIf) stament is false and x = true then...". So your first ElseIf will only execute when `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) <> "F" `

Comment: Thanks alot so far for the attention and pointers. Ive been reading them all and are testing them out right now

Comment: @BMonroe You're welcome. If this answer was useful, please consider accepting it, so others can benefit from it.